# Expose the Object that owns a Property

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, touchesbegan

Though I'm using SpriteKit, this is a general Swift question:

I am creating game classes that will all use SKSpriteNodes (NPC, Player, Powerup, and so on).  I want to store SKSpriteNodes as properties on these objects, rather than inheriting from SKSpriteNode (favoring composition over inheritance).

This works great, except I can't capture which game object class was tapped by a user with the touchesBegan function.  SKScene's nodeAtPoint only returns the instance of the SKSpriteNode, with no way to know which game object owns it.  I can loop through all of my game object instances and compare their sprite nodes to the touched node to create the link I need . . . but that seems very inefficient.

Is there a way to expose the object that 'owns' the property of the touched node?  Or another method to do what I'm describing?  Or should I just inherit from SKSpriteNode like I see in most example games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in this case you need bidirectional relationships - your game objects need to access the nodes but also the nodes need to access their game objects.

I don't think you can completely avoid inheritance in this case. The simplest method would be to inherit from `SKSpriteNode` and add a link to the object that owns it (a `weak` property called `owner`, for example).

Comment: Note that `parent` is already a property of `SKNode`. So something like `owner` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Hi Sulthan.  I was thinking about that method - to inherit SKSpriteNode into a new class with an owner property and constructor to set it.  Glad to hear that's a valid method.  Is there any potential memory leak or other downside to the circular reference?  That's why we'd use 'weak', correct?
I'll mark this the answer in a few hours, if no one pops in with some obscure magical reflection technique.